# Display integer in AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

Am trying to display a list of randomly generated numbers using `AlertDialog`. Problem is, it only accepts Strings(?).I have tried converting the int to String with no luck.I am wondering what alternatives there are to the approach am using.Here is my code:

```
public String generateNumbers() {
    ArrayList<Integer> tempNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int numbers = 6;
    for (int i = 0; i<numbers; i++) {
        tempNumbers.add((int) Math.random()*50 + 1);
    }
    ArrayList<String> finalNumbers = new ArrayList<String>(tempNumbers.size());

    for(Integer nums: tempNumbers) {
        finalNumbers.add(String.valueOf(nums));
    }
    return finalNumbers;
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            context);

    alert.setTitle("Your Numbers");


    myButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_button);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            alert
            .setMessage(generateNumbers());
            alert.show();

        }
    });
```

On the `.setMessage(generateNumbers())` line, it asks me to change the return type of the method to int, but that doesn't help.Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried

```
.setMessage(String.ValueOf(<YourIntValue>);
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.I also tried changing `return finalNumber;` to
`return finalNumbers.toString();` and that worked too.